# Transcoding only finishes once client is timed out?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, wowza, transcoding

Wowza Streaming Engine 4.0.4 from the AMI available here

Currently, I need to wait for the file to finish transcoding before I can use it again.

I'm looking at the logs and I see this:

```
INFO session comment 1420436222 client connectionClosed [1420436222] pingtimeout
INFO server comment - onStreamDestroy: 1
INFO server comment - TranscodingSession.shutdown[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d91412373547415]
INFO transcoder decoder-audio-stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d91412373547415 -
INFO transcoder encoder-audio-stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d91412373547415 {name: "aac"}
```

And then the transcoding is done. and the .tmp file is removed.

I'm assuming that "pingtimeout" is a natural event that happens due to inactivity. I don't want to have the client sit there until it is naturally timed out before I can use the transcoded file.

Is there any way that I can force-close the connection either from the client or the server, without waiting for a "pingtimeout" so that I can use this transcoded file faster?

The client should be able to tell the server "I'm done", and then the server should wrap up all the transcoding operations. Can I do this?

From the client, I'm already calling `NetStream.close()` and `NetStream.dispose()`, but that doesn't seem to help.

### EDIT:

On the client I call `NetStream.close()`
Then I call my custom method that hits the server-side API which saves the file.

Here is a log from a successful attempt:

```
INFO server comment - LiveStreamPacketizerSanJose.endChunkTS[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395]: Add chunk: id:4 a/v/k:251/151/10 duration:10026
INFO server comment - TranscodingSession.close[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395]
INFO stream recordstop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395 -
INFO stream unpublish 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395 -
INFO server comment - onStreamDestroy: 1
INFO stream destroy 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395 -
INFO session disconnect 1958636839 -
INFO server comment - onDisconnect: 1958636839
INFO server comment - TranscodingSession.shutdown[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395]
INFO transcoder decoder-audio-stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395 -
INFO transcoder encoder-audio-stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395 {name: "aac"}
INFO stream unpublish 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395_aac -
INFO server comment - onStreamDestroy: 2
INFO stream destroy 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395_aac -
INFO session connect-pending 50.246.217.38 -
INFO server comment - onConnect: 553457279
INFO session connect 50.246.217.38 -
INFO server comment - onConnectAccept: 553457279
INFO server comment - onStreamCreate: 1
INFO stream create - -
INFO stream play 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395 -
INFO stream seek 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395 -
INFO server comment - Saving thumbnail
INFO server comment - AMFDataList:
[0] saveThumbnail
[1] 3.0
[2] null
[3] 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395
[4] {Array: size: 19053, data: [largeblock]}

INFO server comment - Thumbnail saved /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/recorder/thumb_530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395.jpg
INFO stream stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395 -
INFO server comment - doSave hit
INFO server comment - AMFDataList:
[0] doSave
[1] 4.0
[2] null
[3] 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395

INFO server comment - Starting upload
INFO server comment - getting credentials
INFO server comment - attempting to upload 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395_aac.mp4 to xxxxxxxxxx
INFO server comment - mp4 upload complete xxxxxxxxxx 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395_aac.mp4
INFO server comment - getting credentials
INFO server comment - attempting to upload thumb_530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395.jpg to xxxxxxxxxx
INFO server comment - thumb upload complete xxxxxxxxxx thumb_530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395.jpg
INFO server comment - sending info to client rtmp://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a58/53a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d8/1412696439395_aac.mp4
INFO server comment - deleting 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412696439395
INFO server comment - deleting thumbnail
INFO server comment - deleting mp4 video
INFO server comment - deleting mp4 AAC video
```

The first line indicates a stream.

The second line is the transcoder closing which happens when I stop recording and publishing, then the transcoder shuts down. Now the transcoded file is ready to be used. Unless the transcoder shuts down, I cannot access the transcoded file.

All the lines after that is custom module stuff.

Here's a log from an unsuccessful attempt:

```
INFO server comment - LiveStreamPacketizerSmoothStreaming.addFragment[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485]: Add chunk: type:video id:10 count:15 duration:1007
INFO server comment - TranscodingSession.close[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485]
INFO stream recordstop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO stream unpublish 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO session connect-pending 50.246.217.38 -
INFO server comment - onConnect: 968481495
INFO session connect 50.246.217.38 -
INFO server comment - onConnectAccept: 968481495
INFO server comment - onStreamCreate: 1
INFO stream create - -
INFO stream play 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO stream seek 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO server comment - Saving thumbnail
INFO server comment - AMFDataList:
[0] saveThumbnail
[1] 3.0
[2] null
[3] 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485
[4] {Array: size: 18915, data: [largeblock]}

INFO server comment - Thumbnail saved /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/recorder/thumb_530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485.jpg
INFO server comment - LiveStreamPacketizerSmoothStreaming.addFragment[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485_aac]: Add chunk: type:video id:10 count:15 duration:1007
INFO stream stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO server comment - doSave hit
INFO server comment - AMFDataList:
[0] doSave
[1] 4.0
[2] null
[3] 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485

INFO server comment - Starting upload
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - LiveStreamPacketizerSmoothStreaming.addFragment[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485]: Add chunk: type:video id:10 count:15 duration:1007
INFO server comment - TranscodingSession.close[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485]
INFO stream recordstop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO stream unpublish 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO session comment 404091380 client connectionClosed [404091380] pingtimeout
INFO server comment - onStreamDestroy: 1
INFO stream destroy 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO server comment - TranscodingSession.shutdown[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485]
INFO transcoder decoder-audio-stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 -
INFO transcoder encoder-audio-stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485 {name: "aac"}
INFO session disconnect 404091380 -
INFO server comment - onDisconnect: 404091380
INFO stream unpublish 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485_aac -
INFO server comment - onStreamDestroy: 1
INFO stream destroy 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485_aac -
INFO server comment - Tmp file exists, waiting
INFO server comment - getting credentials
INFO server comment - attempting to upload 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485_aac.mp4 to xxxxxxxxxx
INFO server comment - mp4 upload complete xxxxxxxxxx 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485_aac.mp4
INFO server comment - getting credentials
INFO server comment - attempting to upload thumb_530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485.jpg to xxxxxxxxxx
INFO server comment - thumb upload complete xxxxxxxxxx thumb_530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485.jpg
INFO server comment - sending info to client rtmp://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a58/53a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d8/1412697135485_aac.mp4
INFO server comment - deleting 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412697135485
INFO server comment - deleting thumbnail
INFO server comment - deleting mp4 video
INFO server comment - deleting mp4 AAC video
```

For this one, you can see that the transcoding session closes twice, and then only when the client times out does the transcoding session shut down

### EDIT:

I just attempted this with my custom modules disabled. The same thing happens: Here's a copy/paste of the logs:

```
INFO server comment - LiveStreamPacketizerSmoothStreaming.addFragment[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117_aac]: Add chunk: type:audio id:0 count:32 duration:2053
INFO server comment - TranscodingSession.close[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117]
INFO stream recordstop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117 -
INFO stream unpublish 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117 -
INFO server comment - MediaCasterStreamValidator.init[player/_definst_]: Started
INFO server comment - ServerListenerEC2Variables#ApplicationInstanceNotify.onApplicationInstanceCreate[player/_definst_]: Auto-set application RTSP addresses: internal[bind]:10.213.146.195 external[origin,connection]:54.188.88.9
INFO application app-start _definst_ player/_definst_
INFO session connect-pending 50.246.217.38 -
INFO session connect 50.246.217.38 -
INFO stream create - -
INFO stream play 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117 -
INFO stream seek 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117 -
WARN server comment - Missing function: saveThumbnail
INFO stream stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117 -
INFO session comment 1588047012 client connectionClosed [1588047012] pingtimeout
INFO server comment - TranscodingSession.shutdown[recorder/_definst_/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117]
INFO transcoder decoder-audio-stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117 -
INFO transcoder encoder-audio-stop 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117 {name: "aac"}
INFO stream destroy 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117 -
INFO session disconnect 1588047012 -
INFO stream unpublish 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117_aac -
INFO stream destroy 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d81412700435117_aac -
```

You can see the pingtimeout before the transcoding session shuts down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `NetConnection.close()` after `NetStream.publish("null")` and `NetStream.close()` and this fixed the issue.